# Do not show duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query a MySQL database so I can build a select box. But there are duplicate values being returned. Is there anyway to only show one of each value. Below is my query but when I echo the results it show every row. I need only to show one of each value.

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM ImageInfo";

$db = new connection();

$result = $db->query($query);


while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $content[] = $info;
    }

    $result=array();
    $count = count($content);

 for ($x=0;$x<$count;++$x)
 {
    $result[$x][] = $content[$x]['name'];
 }

echo json_encode($result);
```

and if names row was as follows"

```
name
Mike
Julia
Julia
Julia
Mike
Ben
Tom
Ben
```

when the data echos I am trying to only show

```
Mike
Julia
Ben
Tom
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM ImageInfo";
```

That should do the trick. :)